# Derby database server application using Java

Tags: java, database, server, derby

I am trying to create a Derby database server application using Java. So far i have managed to create client end applications that connect to the derby database which can be accessed from the server I started using derby cmd commands. What i need to make is a java application which, when ran, will start the derby database server. So far all I have come across is this

```
NetworkServerControl serverControl = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("myhost"),1621);

    serverControl.start();
```

Every time I run this code  nothing happens. I am new to Derby and I really need to figure this out for my application. Please don't mention Apache Derby or Oracle derby documentations as i have gone through them and failed to understand. A simple precise solution will be highly appreciated!

P.S. I have added the derbynet.jar file to my project.

Comment: You need to clarify whether you want to start a **separate** Java process which is running the Derby Network Server, or whether you want to have your **own** Java process be able to accept Derby client connections from other processes, as the code will be different for those two different cases.

Comment: @BryanPendleton yes i am trying to create a separate process which will run a derby network server that is able to accept Derby client connections from other processes. Please mention how. Thanks for your reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start derby server from same VM (derby 10.11.1.1) as your application:

download bin package: http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//db/derby/db-derby-10.11.1.1/db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin.zip

extract, and go to db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\lib

copy all jars from lib to your lib folder in your app, add to dependencies.

then in your app execute this:

```
  String[] args = {"start"};
  // for other port;
  //   String[] args = {"start","-p","1088"};

  org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main( args);
```

If you would like to **start separate process** then, use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray)
```

where **cmdarray** is your path to executable and parameters to run it.

Comment: yes! this worked for me. I need some more information. This creates a default server that only listens to localhost on port 1527, I would like to customize this using derby.properties. My question is where should I create this file? In the src folder of my app? please mention that.

Comment: Found the properties file. Working on that right now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use special connection URL, then derby could automatically create your database:

try:

jdbc:derby:${mainDirectory}${dbName};create=true

replace ${mainDirectory} with the path to db, ie: C:\derbyDatabase\

raplce ${dbName} to some name for example: myEmbeddedDatabase

so it could be:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/derbyDatabase/myEmbeddedDatabase;create=true");
```

the create=true means, that it will be created if it doesn't exist

also to end your connection on app exit use:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
```

Comment: No, this is the way to create a **database**. The question asked about how to create a database **server**, which is a Java process which is running the Derby server code and can accept Derby client connections.

Comment: @BryanPendleton yes i am trying to create a separate process which will run a derby network server that is able to accept Derby client connections from other processes. Please mention how. Thanks for your reply! :)

Comment: Do you wish to start the DB in the same VM as your application or as separate process?